# Abbreviated property accessors?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to have an abbreviated property accessor in typescript such as in C# (see below) :

```
private string _myProperty;

public string MyProperty
{
    get => _myProperty;
    set => _myProperty = value;
}
```

or is my code below already the minimal abbreviated version possible ?

```
private _myProperty:string;
    get MyProperty():string {
        return this._myProperty;
    }
    set MyProperty(value:string) {
        this._myProperty = value;
    }
```

Comment: If you're just going to abbreviate to a field, you don't need a property getter/setter pair. Just expose the field itself.

Comment: Correct, but in this case I am looking for the minimalist property getter/setter pair

Comment: Even your C# is too verbose for your example, it should be `public string MyProperty { get; set; }` with no backing variable.

Comment: @crashmstr : True! Thanks

Comment: You might find the closed issue [Define properties like in C# #7628](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7628) to be of interest. But the typescript version is just `myProperty: string;` if it is just a simple get/set kind of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is the shortest version possible, though technically you can leave off the return type annotation on the getter *or* the type annotation on the `value` parameter.